# English translation of The Promised Land by Władysław Reymont

Tags: translation, polish-language, wladyslaw-reymont

Does [*The Promised Land* by Władysław Reymont](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Promised_Land_(novel)) have an English translation?

I could not find it on Amazon. I am very naive about book shopping beyond Amazon and I could not find anything by Googling. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2):

An English translation was published in hardback format by A.A. Knopf in 1927, but there appears to be no English translation currently in print. You may have to use the services of a second-hand bookseller in order to obtain a copy. However, your first port of call should be a public library.

[Goodreads: The Promised Land (2 Volumes)](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18340844-the-promised-land)